# JNI calling C++ method from Android

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface

I am trying to call a c++ method from my Android Activity. I have the c++ source code as well as the .so file for this code.
Is it possible to call this c++ method directly without the JNI wrapper?

If not, do I have to rewrite the logic of the c++ method in JNI wrapper or can I directly invoke my method from there?

Comment: You will need to tell us more about the C++ code. Does it do network access? What inputs/outputs does it have?

Answer (score 0):

Java code can call C++ code via the JNI (Java Native Interface) `native` keyword, or via the [JNA (Java Native Access)](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna) library.